# Overfitting and data leakage in tensorflow/keras neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, anaconda, spyder, figure

Good morning, I'm new in machine learning and neural networks. I am trying to build a fully connected neural network to solve a regression problem. The dataset is composed by 18 features and 1 label, and all of these are physical quantities.

You can find the code below. I upload the figure of the loss function evolution along the epochs (you can find it below). I am not sure if there is overfitting. Someone can explain me why there is or not overfitting?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from keras.regularizers import l2

# =============================================================================
# Scelgo il test size
# =============================================================================
test_size = 0.2

dataset = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")

label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])

y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label)

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y*(y_max_pre_normalize-y_min_pre_normalize)+y_min_pre_normalize
    return final_value

# =============================================================================
# Split
# =============================================================================

X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = test_size, shuffle = True)

y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

# =============================================================================
# Normalizzo
# =============================================================================
scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)


scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)



# =============================================================================
# Creo la rete
# =============================================================================
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(60, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=True, batch_size=250
                    )

history_dict = history.history

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_train_pred = denormalize(y_train_pred)
y_test_pred = denormalize(y_test_pred)


plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_test1),(y_test_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Test')

plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_train1),(y_train_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Train')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(loss_values,'b',label = 'training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label = 'val training loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss Function')
plt.legend()

print("\n\nThe R2 score on the test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test1)))

print("The R2 score on the train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train_pred, y_train1)))
from sklearn import metrics

# Measure MSE error.  
score = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1)
print("\n\nFinal score test (MSE): %0.4f" %(score))
score1 = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1)
print("Final score train (MSE): %0.4f" %(score1))
score2 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1))
print(f"Final score test (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score2))
score3 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1))
print(f"Final score train (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score3))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried alse to do feature importances and to raise n_epochs, these are the results:

Feature Importance:

[image]

No Feature Importace:

[image]

Comment: no, there is no overfitting here, based on your  curves. As you can see the losses are very close. In an overfitted model the validation loss is far above the training loss. Because the model overfit the training data and can't predict well on new data (validation dataset)

Comment: there is overfitting when your model is too complex (too few features, or model got many layers) and learns too well the training dataset, you can prevent it with regularization, dropout layer, more data and other methods

Comment: @AdForte Ok, thanks! But I know that if the training loss is over the validation loss there is overfitting, so this is wrong?

Comment: yeah overfitting is bad, but your model as we can see with the curves, seems goot to me

Comment: This is not really a programming problem, its off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you don't have overfitting! Your training and validation curves are descending together and converging. The clearest sign you could get of overfitting would be a deviation between these two curves, something like this: [image: overfitting ecample]

Since your two curves are descending and are not diverging, it indicates your NN training is healthy.

**HOWEVER**! Your validation curve is suspiciously below the training curve. This hints a possible data leakage (train and test data have been mixed somehow). More info on a nice an short [blog post](https://ibarrond.github.io/data-leakage). In general, you should **split the data before any other preprocessing (normalizing, augmentation, shuffling, etc...)**.

Other causes for this could be some type of regularization (dropout, BN, etc..) that is active while computing the training accuracy and it's deactivated when computing the Validation/Test accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it important if the training loss curve is below (but near) the validation loss curve or the other way around?

Comment: That is yet another question, maybe even worth asking separately! It is weird indeed. I suspect there might me some data leakage happening (training data being used for validation, validation data being used in training, ...). Make sure you separate the training and validation datasets before any shuffling, and that you shuffle them separately.

Comment: @ibarrond I assumed information leakage too. Typically, when I see someone approaching me with this kind of learning curve, he had some bugs in his pipeline or problematic data.
The thing, that validation loss is, in general, lower than train loss may be because of regularization that is applied when training, but not in predicting? 
Despite, the further decreasing val loss seems fishy.

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing Based on my understanding, adding regularization (L1/L2/other changes in the cost function, dropout, BN, etc...) should also impact the validation/test accuracy. Unless... dropout is only deactivated when computing the Validation accuracy and not when computing the training accuracy! That might explain it

Comment: @ibarrond I don't understand the last sentences "Other causes for this could be some type of regularization (dropout, BN, etc..) that is active while computing the training accuracy and it's deactivated when computing the Validation/Test accuracy." Can you explane me? I read the link that you give, maybe the problem is that I build the validation set after normalization in the model.fit line? Because I build test and train set before normalization. What do you think?

Comment: @ibarrond I added some other plot to the principal question, what do yo think?

Comment: @GabrieleValvo Looks like your validation curve is still below the training curve. Checking a bit in `tf` documentation, I believe that you need to explicitly turn off the dropout when calculating the training accuracy. On this github issue there are some hints on how to do so: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19420

Comment: I wouldn't say it is an issue (pr. default) that the validation is lower than the training. I agree that one should think about it, but when the gap isn't bigger, I think it is okay. The test/train split could (indeed) be wrong, but it could also just happen that the validation is closer to the model by chance.

Comment: @ibarrond Thanks, It's really usefull the link that you give me, I also find other articles on internet. But how can I turn off the dropout during validation/testing in my code?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know that, I normally use pure `tensorflow` and avoid high level `keras` because of things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Overfitting is, when the model does not generalize to other data than the training data. When this happen you will have a very (!) low training loss but a high validation loss. You can think of it this way: if you have N points you can fit a N-1 polynomial such that you have a zero training loss (your model hits all your training points perfectly). But, if you apply that model to some other data, it will most likely produce a very high error (see the image below). Here the red line is our model and the green is the true data (+ noice), and you can see in the last picture we get zero training error. In the first, our model is too simple (high train/high validation error), the second is good (low train/low valuidation error) the third and last is too complex i.e overfitting (very low train/high validation error).

Neural network can work in the same way, so by looking at your training vs validation error, you can conclude if it overfits or not

[image: overfitting]

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very usefull. So it is not important if the train loss is over the validation loss as in the picture that I've uploaded?

Comment: Actually, that should be the rare case (I didnt notice that before). You can say that the train loss should always be less than the validation (since the model is adapting to the training data). It can happen though, if the validation set is (somehow) more close to the model, but with this small difference I don't see an issue

Comment: I added some other plot to the principal question, what do you think?

Comment: Ill ask you a question: If you compare the training loss and validation, what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not overfitting as your validation loss isn´t increasing.

Nevertheless, if I were you I would be a little bit skeptical. Try to train your model for even more epochs and watch out for the validation loss.

What you definitely should do, is to observe the following:
- are there duplicates or near-duplicates in the data (creates information leakage from train to test validation split)
- are there features that have a causal connection to the target variable

Edit:

Usually, you have some random component in a real-world dataset, so that rules that are observed in train data aren´t 100% true for validation data. 
Your plot shows that the validation loss is even more decreasing as train loss decreases. Usually, you get to some point in training, where the rules you observe in train data are too specific to describe the whole data. That´s when overfitting begins. Hence, it is weird, that your validation loss doesn´t increase again.

Please check whether your validation loss approaches zero when you´re training for more epochs. If it´s the case I would check your database very carefully.

Let´s assume, that there is a kind of information leakage from the train set to the validation set (through duplicate records for example). Your model would change the weights to describe very specific rules. When applying your model to new data it would fail miserably since the observed connections are not really general. 
Another common data problem is, that features may have an inversed causality.

The thing that validation loss is generally lower than train error is probably depending on dropout and regularization, since it´s applied while training but not for predicting/testing.

I put some emphasis on this because a tiny bug or an error in the data can "fuck up" your whole model.

Comment: Kleine Boesing Thanks for the answer, I tried to increase the n_epochs and the result is that val_loss e trainign_loss converge more than before. The dataset is the result of the sampling of physical quantietis, so the target is connected to the features (not all the features with the same importances, I have to do the feature importances). If you mean records like samples, there are 8500 samples.                                                    I don't understand why are you skeptical??

Comment: So it is not important if the training loss is over (but near) the val loss? Because I know that the model is good (no-overfitting) when the training loss is UNDER the val loss. Do you agree?                                                                                                           p.s I know that it is not the correct place, but I want to uplod pictures in the comment, do you know how can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to see if there are some duplicate in the dataset, but I don't find it also because it is the union of dataset sampled in different physical condition. I don't understand this sentences "The thing that validation loss is generally lower than train error is probably depending on dropout and regularization, since it´s applied while training but not for predicting/testing. ". In you opinion what can I try to do?

Comment: I added some other plot to the principal question, what do you think?